# Button taking 2 click first and then working as needed

Tags: javascript

my code may have some problems but I am unable to find it as I am a very new developer.

I am learning javascript for 3 weeks but I had a problem that when I create any click function it first takes two clicks to work and after it works fine but again on reload it seems the same.

```js
let slider = document.querySelector(".container");
let buttonPull = document.querySelector(".slide-btn")

buttonPull.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (slider.style.right == "-50px") {
    slider.style.right = "0px";
    buttonPull.style.transform = "rotateY(180deg)";
  } else {
    slider.style.right = "-50px"
    buttonPull.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

.container {
  z-index: 0;
  position: fixed;
  right: -50px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 250px;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.25s;
}

.slide {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
  display: flex;
}

.slide-btn {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  left: -25px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: larger;
  top: 102px;
  /* transform: rotateY(180deg); */
  transform-origin: 50%;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 40px;
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: large;
  color: rgb(0, 102, 255);
  transition: step-start 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="slide"></div>
    <button class="slide-btn">&#10094;</button>
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `slider.style.right` doesn't get the style from the stylesheet, only inline styles.

Comment: so what should I do instead?

Comment: IMO duplicate is not helpful.

Comment: See the question linked above.

Comment: I have seen it. I fail to see how it applies to or resolves the problem in the OP.